# How do you start a new window activity in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I tried several things, such as:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, myActivity.class);
startActivity(i)
```

Where it tells me it cannot resolve symbol 'myActivity'

I tried Context.startActivity and extended the class by Context, at that point it just wants me to implement every single method of Context into my class.

How can I just simply make a new activity  visible to the user after an if condition runs into true?

Comment: why do you think `[myActivity].class` would be valid syntax ?

Comment: @a_local_nobody sorry, I am used to using those brackets to indicate placeholders.

Comment: Have u created new Activitiy called name myActivity ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Intent i = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, myActivity.class);
startActivity(i)
```

Here **myActivity** is the name of your second activity (Which you want to open from this intent).

**CurrentActivity** is the name of your current activity

Comment: Did, the first line throws "Cannot resolve constructor" the second line throws "Cannot resolve method 'startActivity' in 'CurrentActivity'"

Comment: Replace `currentActivity` with your current activity name & make sure that you have added the second activity in your manifest file

Comment: CurrentActivity is my current Activity. I just keep the placeholder here for simplification reasons. It's also in my manifest file. Both errors stay.

Comment: Then it should work. Can you add screenshot of your code?

Comment: I managed to fix it with help of my classmate. We moved the two lines into another class.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to understand how to define a class name(Should always start from a capital letter). Then replace the 'myActivity.class' with your new class name.

Make sure that your activity is defined in the AndroidManifest.xml

```
 <activity android:name=".YourActivityName" />
```

if this doesn't fix the problem then try:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), MyClass.class);
```

if view is not found, then implement your class with

```
public class YourClassName extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
   
}}
```

or if you are in a fragment then:

```
 Intent myIntent = new Intent(MyFragment.this.getActivity(), MyClass.class);
```

Comment: That's how mine looks actually. The xml includes the name as well

Comment: @PLANET_XYZ So whats the issue now, if you know all these things?

Comment: That it keeps marking different things as red and I don't know what to do honestly. School just wants me to do a Java project expecting me to know Java from my workplace although we don't work with Java. I'm running out of time, I'm panicking and my teacher doesn't care. So all I want is a solution to how I open a new window activity after a login was successful, like any normal app. Login and afterwards have your app there. But for some reason all solutions I found online keep throwing errors that I can't understand or when trying to fix them implement multiple hundreds of methods.

Comment: answer updated, please check @PLANET_XYZ

Comment: Cannot resolve symbol 'view'...

Comment: Simple implement the class with View.OnClickListener and do the stuff inside onClick(). The onClick() will give you a view.

Comment: Check the updated answer

Comment: Problem is solved, check answer by Kamal Subhani and my comment under there